# Find size of a particular folder inside all the sub folders

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm creating a PowerShell script to email an audit report of all websites I host on my windows server. I also want to print the size of logs folder for every website.

This is what I want. There are several websites in the `c:\inetpub\vhosts` folder. Say `abc.com` and `xyz.com` are the websites. The log files are in `c:\inetpub\vhosts\abc.com\default\logs`. I just want to get the size of all such logs folders like below.

```
1. c:\inetpub\vhosts\abc.com\default\logs              100 MB
2. c:\inetpub\vhosts\xyz.com.com\default\logs          120 MB
```

Just like displaying the folder size of `c:\inetpub\vhosts\*\default\logs` for every match of *.

How can I do this with PowerShell?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use your favorite search engine using your post title. You will note that you get hits of sample scripts for what your use case is that you can tweak as needed.

> Getting Directory Sizes in PowerShell
>
> You have probably asked this question hundreds of times, “How big is
>   that folder?” Of course, the typical GUI way to find out is to
>   right-click the folder in Windows Explorer and open the folder’s
>   properties. As with all things GUI, this does not scale well. For
>   example, what if you need the size for 100 different folders?
>
> https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/25/getting-directory-sizes-in-powershell
>
> Search and Find Folders Using PowerShell
>
> Hiin my previous upload {
>   http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Search-for-Files-Using-340397aa
>   }, I write about  "How to search and Find Files using Powershell", 
>   and in this upload you can search for Folders.
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Search-and-Find-Folders-af9c86ad
>
> PowerShell Function to report folder sizes (Get-FolderSize)
>
> Get-FolderSize Function displays size of all folders in a specified
>   path. This tool is useful if you want to determine large folders in a
>   particular path. Particularly useful to manually monitor user home
>   foldeers. The function displays folder name, full path and size in
>   GB######
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Function-to-6bebe734

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing the below code. Might not be the best code! But, I got what I wanted.

```
#To calculate log file size of DNN wesbite at C:\inetpub\vhosts\*\httpdocs\Portals\_default\Logs

    function Get-FolderSize {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    $Path,
    [ValidateSet("KB","MB","GB")]
    $Units = "MB"
    )
      if ( (Test-Path $Path) -and (Get-Item $Path).PSIsContainer ) {
        $Measure = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
        $Sum = $Measure.Sum / "1$Units"
        echo $Sum

      }
    }

    Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Inetpub\vhosts -Directory | Select -exp Name > websites.txt
    echo '' > log-size.txt

    foreach ($website in get-content websites.txt) {
        $path = "C:\inetpub\vhosts\" + $website + "\httpdocs\Portals\_default\Logs"
        $logSize = get-foldersize $path
        $logSize = [INT] $logSize
        if ($logSize -gt 25 )
            {
            $logSize = $website + " :" + "$logSize" + "MB"
            echo $logSize >> log-size.txt
            }
    }
```